# Is Mrs. Putnum's dress indicative of anything significant during this Season 2 scene in The Handmaid's Tale?

Tags: character, analysis, costume, the-handmaids-tale

In Season 2, Episode 5 of the TV series adaptation of *The Handmaid's Tale*, viewers are thrown a monkey wrench on the June & Nick romance when The Waterfords force Nick into a child-bride wedding ceremony called, Prayvaganza where he is to be wed to a new character named Eden.

My question however, relates to the clothing of another character apart of the scene. In Gilead different classes of people are to wear different colored/styled clothing. The Commanders' wives for instance are meant to be wearing a more conservative emerald green dress, but one character [Naomi Putnam](https://the-handmaids-tale.fandom.com/wiki/Naomi_Putnam) is seen wearing a lighter shade of green and also has some ruffles, which most other dresses do not. (There is also another character sitting at the opposite end of the row that also is wearing a lighter shade than the other wives).

[image: Wives]

Is there any significance (in-universe) as to why some of the Commander's wives would be permitted to have these variations? Is the lighter shade indicative of a rank within a rank, or was THIS just the TV show's way of getting some personality traits, characterization, and/or loyalty to the cause across?

Comment: The wives are the most privileged females in the state - it doesn't surprise me that they are allowed more room to experiment with fashion than the Handmaids or Marthas.  In my mind I'm sure they have a grim fashion shop with 5 different options in it - as grim as the grocery store is.  I'm not answering because I'd love to hear an interview with the director, art director, or costume designers. Serena Joy may be wearing a very similar shade to the person to her right but it looks here to be very slightly paler and has a different neckline.

Comment: @iandotkelly You are probably right and I totally agree, but I too was just curious if there was anything else beyond it that the EPs/etc might of shed some light on -- even something in the book(s) perhaps.